# setting datepicker for each row iterated using logic:iterate

Tags: javascript, jsp

i am iterating a list using `logic:iterate` in **jsp** 
for each row that was iterated by `logic:iterate` we need to provide datepicker for the field named dateOfDetection.

code for refrence:

```
<logic:iterate  id="dbOject"   name="fakeNotesListInSession" scope="session"
indexId="tableCounter"> 

<TR >
<TD> <html:text name="dbOject" property="dateOfDetection"   readonly="true" size="10" ></html:text>
<img src="web/images/cal[2].gif" id="trigger<%=tableCounter.toString()%>" alt="Calendar"/> 
<script type="text/javascript">

                     Calendar.setup({

                           inputField : "dateOfDetection", 

                           ifFormat : "%d/%m/%Y", 

                           button : "trigger<%=tableCounter.toString()%>" 
                     });

                   </script></TD>

         <TD> <html:text name="dbOject" property="fives"  size = "5"  ></html:text></TD>

         <TD> <html:text name="dbOject" property="tens"  size = "5"  ></html:text></TD>


           </TR>

 </logic:iterate>
```

---

for each row it is iterating, the date picker is coming, but when we select the date value, it is setting value to the first row only.
reason is "inside Calendar.setup function we have given inputField  as "dateOfDetection". this is defined as  String dateOfDetection[]=null; inside action form, so that it can be fetched as array in the action claas.

Comment: Pl update on this quickly

Comment: Any solution  for the above problem.